# VaR : Student-t GARCH

Tags: programming, risk, risk-management, garch, value-at-risk

I have a question on the VaR estimation via the student t GARCH model.

Under this framework, the one day ahead VaR estimate is calculated by the following formula:

$$VaR_{p}=\mu_{t+1}+\sigma_{t+1}\sqrt{\frac{\nu-2}{\nu}}z_{p}$$

Where $z_{p}$ is the unconditional student-t quantile of the estimated innovations.

As you know, for the  parameters estimation of the Student-t GARCH model the corresponding (Student-t) log likelihood function should be maximised (Maximum Likelihood methodology). When this estimation is conducted the $\nu$ (degrees of freedom) is also estimated since it is one of the parameters of the log likelihood function.

The question is if this is the actual $\nu$ (degrees of freedom) that we need to use in the above formula or I have to re-estimate it by fitting the Student-t pdf to the estimated innovations (residuals)? If this is the case can this fitting (parameters estimation) be done via the **fitdist** MATLAB function (Student-t is not included in the provided range of distributions)?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing the residuals versus the **standardized** residuals ( 0 mean and unit variance residuals) and/or the student distribution vs the **standardized** student distribution.

> The degree of freedom you obtain from the MLE estimation is the one
>   you should use in the Var formula.

The **standardized** student Garch model is:

$Y_{t} = \mu_{t} + \sigma_{t} z_{t} \qquad z_{t} \sim t(0,1,v)\qquad, v>2$

where $z_{t}$ are the **standardized** student innovations (see Bollerslev original formulation).
You always need to have standardized innovations since the conditional variance of residuals  $ (\epsilon_{t}= \sigma_{t} z_{t})$ must be  equal to $\sigma_{t}^{2}$ :
$Var(\epsilon_{t}) = \sigma_{t}^{2}$ only if $Var(z_{t})=1$

When you fit your model you obtain the residuals : $ \epsilon_{t}= \sigma_{t} z_{t}$

Then the standardized t-innovations are recovered by :

$z_{t} =   \epsilon_{t} \sigma_{t}^{-1} $

MLE estimate is based on the fact that those innovations are IID. The loglikelihood estimation returns arch+garch parameters and parameters of the distribution of the error term : in this case $v$

Finally the VaR is given by :

$Var_{t} = \mu_{t} + \sigma_{t} st_{\alpha,v}  $

with $st_{\alpha,v} $ being the left quantile at $ \alpha $% for the **standardized** t-distribution with (estimated) number of degrees of freedom ($v$).

However if you use a **non**-standardized t-distribution to express the VaR , and since you know that the variance of the t-distribution is   :  $ Variance(f_{tdist})=\sigma_{tdist}^{2}= \frac{v}{v-2} $
you can expressed the VaR  by rescaling the student distribution as:

\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
Var_{t} & = \mu_{t} + \sigma_{t} st_{\alpha,v} \\
 & = \mu_{t} + \sigma_{t} \left(     t_{\alpha,v }   \sigma_{tdist}^{-1} \right)\\
 & = \mu_{t} + \sigma_{t} \left(     t_{\alpha,v }   \left[\sqrt\frac{v}{v-2}  \right]^{-1} \right)\\
& = \mu_{t} + \sigma_{t}      t_{\alpha,v }    \sqrt\frac{v-2}{v}    \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Note that $st_{\alpha,v}$  , the standardized t-distribution is different of $t_{\alpha,v}$  the non-standardized t-distribution

The MLE estimation is based on $st_{\alpha,v}$  , from the estimation you get $v$ and then the factor $ \sqrt\frac{v-2}{v} $ is just a rescaling operation which does not participate to the MLE estimation.

In Matlab you can use the [tLocationScaleDistribution](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.tlocationscaledistribution.html) with $\mu =0$ and $\sigma = 1 $.

Comment: I was under the impression that degrees of freedom $\nu$ for Student's t distribution cannot be estimated via MLE as the likelihood is not bounded in the parameters, i.e. the likelihood can always be increased by increasing $\nu$ and $\sigma$. Is this not the case?